# Comparing Datetime in Jinja

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

I am working with `Django`. I have following variable in my template:

- `startingTime` it's value come from database (`DateTimeField`)
- `currentTime` actually a variable that contain the value of `datetime.datetime.now()`
- `durationInMinits` actually a integer field, contain `int` value (in minutes)

Now I need to determine if the difference between `currentTime` and `startingTime` is greater than `durationInMinits` or not.

I have tried in my `template.py` like this:

```
{% if startingTime < currentTime < startingTime + durationInMinits %}
    <p> This will display if current time is greter than startingtime, but duration is not over </p>
{% endif %}
```

But it gives error. Please suggest how can I compare time in jinja?

Comment: {% if startingTime < currentTime and currentTime < startingTime + durationInMinits %}

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, it gives `Could not parse the remainder: '+' from '+'`

Comment: Can you specify what error you get? Are you sure you are rendering jinja and not the Django template engine?

Comment: yeah, I am rendering the jinja, and it says `Could not parse the remainder: '+' from '+' ` error. basically, it gives an error every time when I use the `+` symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct a timespan. You thus pass `durationInMinits` as:

```
from datetime import timedelta

durationInMinits = timedelta(minutes=durationInMinits)
```

If that is not possible, you can pass the `timedelta` as context, so:

context = {
'startingTime': datetime(2021, 8, 9),
'currentTime': datetime.now(),
'durationInMinits': 800,
'timedelta': timedelta
}

and then render with:

```
{% if startingTime < currentTime < startingTime + timedelta(minutes=durationInMinits) %}
    …
{% endif %}
```